# jquery populate json data for radio buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, edit

i have an edit form with input fields and radio buttons, as page is loaded a function retrieves data via json to fill those fields and edit them.

i have no problem with input fields, i get the data to fill them this way:

```
var fields =  $("#name").val(element.name);$("#surname").val(element.surname);
```

the problem is when i try to get the value for a radio button group, like

```
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="H" id="sex_0" />
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="M" id="sexo_1" />
```

how can i put the right radio button checked based on the json data retrieved?

many thanks!

Comment: can you post ur  json data...

Comment: do you have `element.sex` in the json?

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing what your JSON looks like, generally speaking this is how you check and uncheck a radio box or check box.

```
//Check a radio button
$('#sex_0').attr('checked', 'checked'); 

//Uncheck a radio button
$('#sexo_1').removeAttr('checked');
```

PS - bipen's solution is probably closer to what you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `val()` itself, though you need to make sure of selector you use

```
 $('input[name="sex"]').val('H'); //json return value here.
```